# One way replication from MSSQL2005 to MYSQL 5.x

Tags: sql-server, mysql, sql-server-2005, replication, mysql-replication

I have a mysql database acting as our websever backend. We have our production mssql server that we would like data pushed from, to our mysql server.

I have successfully made the mysql server an ODBC system datasource.

I can do an insert update statement into the mysql table from our mssql table, so I know I can indeed connect to the mysql server via the system ODBC connection.

I have setup a local publication using:

```
    -- Adding the transactional publication
use [repl_test]
exec sp_addpublication @publication = N'Repl_test'
, @description = N'Transactional publication of database'
, @sync_method = N'concurrent_c'
, @retention = 0
, @allow_push = N'true'
, @allow_pull = N'false'
, @allow_anonymous = N'true'
, @enabled_for_internet = N'false'
, @snapshot_in_defaultfolder = N'true'
, @compress_snapshot = N'false'
, @ftp_port = 21
, @allow_subscription_copy = N'false'
, @add_to_active_directory = N'false'
, @repl_freq = N'continuous'
, @status = N'active'
, @independent_agent = N'true'
, @immediate_sync = N'true'
, @allow_sync_tran = N'false'
, @allow_queued_tran = N'false'
, @allow_dts = N'false'
, @replicate_ddl = 0
, @allow_initialize_from_backup = N'false'
, @enabled_for_p2p = N'false'
, @enabled_for_het_sub = N'true'
, @autogen_sync_procs = 'false'
GO
```

I have added a snapshot agent:

```
    exec sp_addpublication_snapshot @publication = N'Repl_test'
, @frequency_type = 4
, @frequency_interval = 4
, @frequency_relative_interval = 1
, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0
, @frequency_subday = 4
, @frequency_subday_interval = 1
, @active_start_time_of_day = 0
, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959
, @active_start_date = 0
, @active_end_date = 0
, @job_login = null
, @job_password = null
, @publisher_security_mode = 1
GO
```

I have added a subscription for a non-mssql server:

```
use [repl_test]
exec sp_addsubscription @publication = N'Repl_test'
, @subscriber = N'MYSQL'
, @destination_db = N'TestTable'
, @subscription_type = N'Push'
, @sync_type = N'automatic'
, @article = N'all'
, @update_mode = N'read only'
, @subscriber_type = 1
```

I have setup a push subscription agent also:

```
exec sp_addpushsubscription_agent @publication = N'Repl_test'
, @subscriber = N'MYSQL'
, @subscriber_db = N'TestTable'
, @job_login = null
, @job_password = null
, @subscriber_security_mode = 0
, @subscriber_login = N'root'
, @subscriber_password = 'PASSWORD'
, @subscriber_provider = N'MSDASQL'
, @subscriber_datasrc = N'mysqltest'
, @frequency_type = 64
, @frequency_interval = 0
, @frequency_relative_interval = 0
, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0
, @frequency_subday = 0
, @frequency_subday_interval = 0
, @active_start_time_of_day = 0
, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959
, @active_start_date = 20101202
, @active_end_date = 99991231
, @enabled_for_syncmgr = N'False'
, @dts_package_location = N'Distributor'
GO
```

Everything gets created without a hitch, I make sure that I have at least one article selected (which there is only one table called "TestTable".

When running the replication monitor I get the errors of:

```
Error messages:
The process could not connect to Subscriber 'MYSQL'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20084)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20084
 Data source name not found and no default driver specified (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: IM002)
Get help: http://help/IM002
```

I am screwing up, I think at the "@subscriber_provider" and "@subscriber_datasrc". If it can't be done via replication we'll have to setup some sort of SQL Agent job to do the updating/copying.

Any help is welcomed.

**Update1** 
I have been successful in the initial replication of the "TestTable". I had to use the stored proc of sp_addarticle in order for the replication to NOT drop the mysql table on connection.

```
   exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'Repl_test'
, @article = N'TestTable'
, @source_owner = N'dbo'
, @source_object = N'TestTable'
, @type = N'logbased'
, @pre_creation_cmd = N'none'
, @ins_cmd = N'SQL'
, @del_cmd = N'SQL'
, @upd_cmd = N'SQL'
, @schema_option = 0x20025081
, @status = 24
GO
```

The replication is now complaining of a dupe unique key in my table. I think I still have more playing around to do with the add article stored proc.

**Update2**
Receive error below during initial replication

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"MSREPL7" set xactts = _binary'\0\0\0}\0\04\0\0\0\0', timecol = {ts '2010-12-' at line 1 (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20046)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20046
```

Then subsequent errors are about a duplicate key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it solved.

the variable @force_reinit_subscription in sp_addrticlecolumn must be either null or 0.

I commented that line out, and it's working like a charm.

Here is the full working code:

```
--step 1

-- Adding the transactional publication
use [repl_test]
exec sp_addpublication @publication = N'Repl_test'
, @description = N'Transactional publication of database'
, @sync_method = N'concurrent_c'
, @retention = 0
, @allow_push = N'true'
, @allow_pull = N'false'
, @allow_anonymous = N'true'
, @enabled_for_internet = N'false'
, @snapshot_in_defaultfolder = N'true'
, @compress_snapshot = N'false'
, @ftp_port = 21
, @allow_subscription_copy = N'false'
, @add_to_active_directory = N'false'
, @repl_freq = N'continuous'
, @status = N'active'
, @independent_agent = N'true'
, @immediate_sync = N'true'
, @allow_sync_tran = N'false'
, @allow_queued_tran = N'false'
, @allow_dts = N'false'
, @replicate_ddl = 0
, @allow_initialize_from_backup = N'false'
, @enabled_for_p2p = N'false'
, @enabled_for_het_sub = N'true'
, @autogen_sync_procs = 'false'
GO
--add the article to the publication
exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'Repl_test'
, @article = N'TestTable'
, @source_owner = N'dbo'
, @source_object = N'TestTable'
, @type = N'logbased'
, @pre_creation_cmd = N'none'
, @ins_cmd = N'SQL'
, @del_cmd = N'SQL'
, @upd_cmd = N'SQL'
, @schema_option = 0x8000000
, @status = 24
GO

--add all of the columns to the article
exec sp_articlecolumn @publication = N'Repl_test'
, @article = N'TestTable'
, @refresh_synctran_procs = 1
GO

--end step1

--step2
--add the publication snaphot
exec sp_addpublication_snapshot @publication = N'Repl_test'
, @frequency_type = 4
, @frequency_interval = 4
, @frequency_relative_interval = 1
, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0
, @frequency_subday = 4
, @frequency_subday_interval = 1
, @active_start_time_of_day = 0
, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959
, @active_start_date = 0
, @active_end_date = 0
, @job_login = null
, @job_password = null
, @publisher_security_mode = 1
GO
--end step2

--step3
--add the subscriber(s)
use [repl_test]
exec sp_addsubscription @publication = N'Repl_test'
, @subscriber = N'mysqltest'
, @destination_db = N'repl_test'
, @subscription_type = N'Push'
, @sync_type = N'automatic'
, @article = N'all'
, @update_mode = N'read only'
, @subscriber_type = 3
GO

--add the pushing subscription agent
exec sp_addpushsubscription_agent @publication = N'Repl_test'
, @subscriber = N'mysqltest'
, @subscriber_db = N'repl_test'
, @job_login = null
, @job_password = null
, @subscriber_security_mode = 0
, @subscriber_login = N'root'
, @subscriber_password = 'PASSWORD'
, @subscriber_provider = N'MSDASQL'
, @subscriber_datasrc = N'mysqltest'
, @frequency_type = 64
, @frequency_interval = 1
, @frequency_relative_interval = 0
, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0
, @frequency_subday = 0
, @frequency_subday_interval = 0
, @active_start_time_of_day = 0
, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959
, @active_start_date = 20101202
, @active_end_date = 99991231
, @enabled_for_syncmgr = N'False'
, @dts_package_location = N'Distributor'
GO
--end step3
```